# How can I connect to a router through a switched ethernet network?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, switch, mac-address

I have a computer and a router connected at different positions to a switched ethernet network. I want to connect them as if I had plugged my computer directly into the router.

As I understand it, ethernet networks send data in frames using to and from MAC addresses, so it should be possible for any two connected devices to communicate directly, without first receiving an IP address from the main router, right?

Comment: yes, thats true, but its useless to send L2 traffic to a router unless the frames contains L3 protocol packets. the vast majority of protocols used to actually perform productivity work these days are L3, and most L2 protocols are simply for Carrier (ethernet, wifi, etc), network management, and logistics (ARP, STP, etc)

Comment: @Frank But can't I establish an IP connection to the router using its MAC address?

Comment: yes and no. what you describe is how DHCP works. the system without an IP sends a broadcast frame addressed to mac addr FFFFFFFFFFFF. all hosts on the lan recieve that frame, and decode the layer 3 (IP) packet inside it, and the layer4 segment within the packet which is addressed to TCP\68 (DHCP services). All that said, note that only TCP services have "connections". Most Layer2 protocols and all UDP services are "connectionless". they contain no info about the order the frames were sent, and does not notice if it misses a frame or 3.

Comment: you may want to look into encapsulation: http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/the-osi-model/179-osi-data-encapsulation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the key to working with MAC addresses is the **ARP** table, a table that links neighbouring IP addresses (IP addresses on the local network) to MAC addresses.

All you need to do is use `ip neigh add` to link your router's MAC address to an IP address, then route via that IP address as usual:

```
#!/bin/sh
DEV="eth0"
ROUTER="192.168.0.1"
MAC="${1:-01:23:45:67:89:ab}"
IP="192.168.0.5/24"

ip link set "$DEV" up
ip addr add "$IP" dev "$DEV"
ip neigh add "$ROUTER" lladdr "$MAC" dev "$DEV"
ip route add default via "$ROUTER"
```

<sup>[View the full script I'm using on GitHub Gist.](https://gist.github.com/jb/2fb379f713c08677ec8c)</sup>

The above script sets up a static IP connection to a router by its MAC address (which you can specify on the command line, or specify a default MAC address in the code).

If you're using static IP instead of DCHP, you may need to configure nameservers (`resolv.conf`).